# Logic to help serialize inventory in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, serialization, automation, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

This is my first post on stackoverflow so I apologize in advance for any errors.

My wife and I are ramping up our small business and I'd like to get some automation set up to generate SKUs for items (we will be posting 1K+ items).

The "Master List of Inventory" picture below shows the sheet I'm using.

**Desired outcome:** We automate a SKU based on the following criteria;

- The first two characters of the SKU are based off the "Category" that I select in Column E. See picture "SKU Categories" for the abbreviations of each SKU (that is also the source of truth for the data validation drop downs on the first tab).
- There is a hyphen separate the first category abbreviation and the last 4 characters
- My preference would be that the last 4 characters can be done in a sequential manner. See "SKU Categories" picture for path I was heading down. I used IF and VLOOKUP statements to see if a SKU had been used or not. If it's not possible to do this in a sequential manner any randomized 4 digits could be used (as long as there are no duplicates).

**Other requirements**

- there should not be any duplicate SKUs
- Bonus!! If this could be done in a way that allows for future additions of SKUs that would be awesome. My wife may add and/or change some of the logic.

I can hold my own with basic formulas but my head started hurting trying to figure this out on my own.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions you can provide. Lmk if there is other info I can add!

Jeff

[Master List of Inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jzEe.png)
[SKU Categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOdPM.png)

I'm trying to create a SKU generator.

Comment: Why don't you share a spreadsheet illustrating what you have, what you've tried, and what you expect to have. All with dummy data. This is the right habit to have when asking questions in this forum. Not only you will get quicker responses and your problem solved, but also, if you intended to learn and improve your skills, they will show you how to do so. Sharing screenshots only would require more efforts from the person looking at your problem, which not everyone is eager to do.